# Drinking beer with a straw

Tags: alcohol-level

Does drinking strong beer with a straw get you drunk faster? 
If this is true what causes this effect?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is caused by two things.

1)
When you drink with a straw the liquid touches your palate (upper part of your mouth) more, the skin in your palate is thin and strongly circulated (with blood) this accelerates the absorption of alcohol in the blood.

2)
Sucking fluid trough the straw requires a lower than ambient pressure in the lungs and mouth. This lower pressure causes more of the alcohol to evaporate, this alcohol is absorbed by the lungs again increasing alcohol absorption.

While drinking with a straw will get you drunk faster it will not necessarily get you more drunk as this is mostly just related to the amount of consumed alcohol.